# mysql vulnerabilities. save data in php files or mysql databases

Tags: php, mysql, security

i started learning a bit about mysql and while i was reading i was thinking that the security vulnerabilities on mysql are pretty immense and can't be well covered if someone doesn't truly understand pretty much everything about mysql.

if i have a website that will store not a very big volume of information, would it be bad to store it in .php files?

what are the implications and vulnerabilities of this?

it seems to me that the risk is far smaller because if the .php file doesn't have an echo statement, if you try to access it all you get is a blank page, and if you are unable to 'send code' by user input and send files to the website it should be secure as far as the website is concerned (obviously that if the server itself is hacked the attacker pretty much has the control of everything but that's not the point on this matter)

---

update to the question.

it seems that what i've written above isn't producing the kind of answers that i expect and so i will try to simplify.

what i'm looking for here is why are databases more secure than flat files without bias because most people i've read stuff about on this subject will just say databases are more secure but can't say why. yes they're faster and it's easier to manipulate the data especially if it's complex or with multiple users and there is a lot of info. about that and it's easy to understand why.

the fact is that when i started reading about mysql a few days ago i saw that if your php is compromised most likely so are the databases so writing good secure php code is probably the first and most important line of defense to your mysql databases.

if your php is uncompromised so is the information you stored in php files so if you write good secure php, the security of plain php files will be good.

having databases also makes you use php functions that usually you wouldn't use and some of them possess real security holes that have to be "patched up" so writing good secure php code to work with databases is more complex than writing equally secure code to work with plain files.

also when you have apache/php/mysql installed you have 3 things that may have entry points for hackers if they're not correctly configured and maintained, if you cut mysql loose you only have 2, you won't have to bother with sql injection for example because with no databases that's impossible to happen, you may inject all sql you want but you will get nothing.

so for managing small amounts of data, plain files seem to me like a secure, a bit more complicated to work with the data, slower but not relevant considering that it's a small amount of data we are talking about.

why may these deductions be wrong is the information i'm looking for with this.

Comment: Why would the storage matter? What matters is what you do with stored data. Saving something to PHP file that deletes a file on a server is a recipe for shooting your own foot.

Comment: @Furicane that was not the point and has nothing to do with the question. and i'm talking about storing information, not 'commands to delete stuff in valid php code'

Comment: So you're saying that storing some data in mysql is a larger security hole than storing the data in a PHP file because if there's no `echo` statement, nothing will happen? I just told you that it could, because php files are executable. Theoretically, someone can store anything in that file, including malicious code. If someone stored that in mysql, the only problem is how you pull that data and what you do with it. Plus, PHP commands aren't evaluated once pulled from mysql, if you store that stuff in a php file then they are executable. Without more info, I doubt any further help is possible.

Comment: @Furicane i know php files are executable. you say that in the hypothetical situation that i created someone can store something in that file, my question is, how could they store/alter/see something from that file on the given situation? also i didn't said that nothing will happen without an echo statement, i said that you won't be able to see the info. when you access the page (or the print statement or some others). also for 'store information' i'm referring to, lets say, a wordlist for example. the .php file would have a $x='blah'; line on it. how someone would be able to see 'blah'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apples and oranges.

You can go to a drag race with a Hummer and complete the race but you will surely be in last compared to a Bugatti.  Take a Bugatti off-road and it will definitely fall behind the Hummer.

PHP is a server side scripting language.  Data storage and retrieval is not the primary consideration in PHP.

mySQL is a relational database management system.  It's design is 100% purposed for data storage, retrieval, and security.

What's your plan for data storage and retrieval in PHP?  It seems like will have to do a lot of unnecessary work re-inventing the wheel to achieve this.  Why would you?

Without understanding what security concerns you are specifically worried about in mySQL there isn't much more to add.

Edit: [An article calling out the general differences.](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/storing-data-with-php-flat-file-or-database.html)

Comment: it was a simple question with probably a simple (and maybe big) answer that i don't know. what are the security implications of storing, let's say, non-malicious string/array data in a .php file? how someone could see it or modify it. also your analogy is pretty funny because chances are the bugatti wouldn't finish the off road course xD

Comment: @wxiiir haha good point :)  So to answer your question regarding access of data in flat php files.. it would be coupled with access to your file system.  Consider the recent exploit of TimThumb (a popular thumbnail creating script in PHP) http://wpcandy.com/reports/timthumb-security-vulnerability-discovered.  Exploiters figured out how to allow themselves to upload and execute arbitrary PHP code in the TimThumb cache directory.  Now imagine if this PHP code simply dumped the contents of all files in the web directory... they now have all your data.

Comment: this is good information. let's say that if i had this website that was hacked they could easily see the information that would be stored on plain php files (if i stored it this way). now the question is, why wouldn't they be able to see the information of my databases (if instead of using plain php files i would use a mysql database)? 

i guess that it wouldn't be of any difficulty for hackers to access the databases when able to execute any php code inside the website, maybe it would take them 10 more minutes at best than accessing the information on plain php files, am i wrong?

Comment: mySQL databases should be setup in another part of the server or on a different server entirely; not exposed to the internet only to server-side code.  Passwords & connection strings should be kept outside of the web dir  in server configuration files.  Thus access to the web directory doesn't imply immediate access to the database; some reverse engineering would be needed.  mySQL also allows for easy field level encryption.  This would be more complicated if you were to do it manually in PHP.

Comment: i guess this pretty much answers my question, if a website script can access the database, so the scripts that the hackers will put on the website or the original script but modified by the hacker, so it will delay them maybe a lot maybe not but will not stop them. thank you for replying, i will choose your response even though the comments were the more elucidating. storing data in flat files in a way that will delay hackers it's doable too, it will not delay them as much but it's doable.

Comment: -1 sql injection is very useful for obtaining data from a mysql database,  and in most cases its impossible for an attacker to delete or modify this information as query stacking isn't supported by the vast majority of databases.

Answer (score 0):

These two points will cover most security issues:

1)Learn PDO and the prepared statement protocol. This will take care of most if not all SQL injection issues. Do not send raw SQL to a database.

2)Sanitize all your GET and POST data that comes into PHP. This will take care of most XSS.

Many frameworks in other languages do this for you, but the PHP newbie will just use bare PHP and open himself up to all kinds of attacks. That is why PHP is "unsafe."

Read up on security, and try to implement some of the pointers that you feel are important. No language, framework, platform, etc is 100% secure. Just like everything else in life, you take as many steps as possible to minimize the risk.

Comment: i already knew about the sql injection and i coded many stuff that gathered post and get data and i sanitize it properly every time. now you said that the php newbie will just store stuff on bare php and open himself to every kind of attacks and that's why php is unsafe, that's the information i'm interested in, that's why i created this hypothetical situation to see if someone would know of a known way to retrieve the data saved on the 'flat php files'